# Facing issues while using two or more request with GuzzleHttp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle6, guzzle

I'm facing a problem with my `Laravel 5.4` appication where I'm using GuzzleHttp client service, I'm trying to access urls to get a login token then get a login information, while trying in postman I'm able to get the data something like this:

[image: for token]

Then I'm fetching the login information something like this:

[image: Login info]

Now while fetching the same with my guzzle http client I'm using a general controller which get the information of the url to be passed and the request parameters to be sent so in my controller I'm having something like this:

```
public function __construct(GuzzleHttp\Client $client)
{
    $this->client = $client;
}

public function getRequest( Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->client->post($request->url, [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => json_encode($request->request_data)
    ]);

    $response = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($request->getBody());
    return response()->json(['data' => json_decode($response->d)],$request->getStatusCode());
}
```

Now while accessing I'm getting not proper results:

First the Login url:

[image: Local host]

Then the login information:

I get an unauthorized error:

[image: Localhost login info]

I don't know what to do, even there is hardly a fraction of seconds to call the next url, I've checked in postman no cookies are being used or no session data is involved. don't know what to do, help me out with this.

Comment: Have you attempted creating a new instance of Guzzle each time you make the request, rather than inject it into the controller?

Comment: Nopes not yet. Let me try.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin No it didn't work out. Still the same.

Comment: are you sure `request_data` makes it into the controller?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin same controller is giving me output for login, I guess the request_data makes to the controller.

Comment: You should be sure it gets there..., so that you can easily trace where the issue is coming from.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin i'm pretty sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Change $request variable name in this line `$request = $this->client->post($request->url, [` , you override $request variable from function argument. And test again.

Your code should be like this

```
    public function getRequest( Request $request)
{
    $request2 = $this->client->post($request->url, [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => json_encode($request->request_data)
    ]);

    $response = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($request2->getBody());
    return response()->json(['data' => json_decode($response->d)],$request->getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you, you mean to say that I should take the $request variables into a variable? Like `$data = $request->input('request_data');` and `$url = $request->input('url');` and then pass to $this->client.

Comment: I added it in answer

Comment: It didn't change any situation, still the same error.